# How can I see if two protocol buffer files (.pb) are the same?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers

I have a bunch of protocol buffer files of models I created with `Tensorflow` and `Keras`, and I would like to see which ones are identical. My first thought was to use `hashlib.md5`, but I have found that running the same script to freeze the graph into an `.pb` file results in `.pb` files with different hashes.

Here is how I created the `.pb` files:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants
K.set_learning_phase(0)
keras_session = K.get_session()
graph = keras_session.graph
graph.as_default()
keep_var_names=None
output_names=[out.op.name for out in model.outputs]
clear_devices=True
with graph.as_default():
    freeze_var_names = list(set(v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()).difference(keep_var_names or []))
    output_names = output_names or []
    output_names += [v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()]
    # Graph -> GraphDef ProtoBuf
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
    if clear_devices:
        for node in input_graph_def.node:
            node.device = ""
    frozen_graph = convert_variables_to_constants(keras_session, input_graph_def,
                                                  output_names, freeze_var_names)
tf.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, "model", "my_model.pb", as_text=False)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to compare exactly in these protocol buffer files ? If a simple hash is not enough, you need to be more precise than that.

Comment: Computers are not good at doing random stuff, so I bet that you used that md5 lib in the wrong way. To the best of my knowledge you should get the same hash if you run it multiple times on the same input as long as you use the same number of passes and salt.

Comment: It was the script to freeze the graph into a .pb file that gave different results, not the script to find the hash. I edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: Oh I see, are they really identical after decoding then? In that case the only thing I can come up with is decoding the files and running a hash on them and then compare hashes. Edit: I realized that they are protobuf message definitions, not encoded data. Right? In that case, forget what I said :D

Comment: Decode them like this?
```
with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
```?

Comment: It's hard to grasp what is going on if you don't post some examples of what the input is, how you generate the `.pb` files and how they are different at each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

protobuf is not formally guaranteed to have the exact same output from semantically identical inputs; in particular:

- the order of fields is allowed to vary:

  - although it is common for data written in a single lump to be in field/tag order, it is not *required* to be (and readers are *required* to accept out-of-order fields)
  - data constructed by multiple writes (concatenation) has no guarantee of field order
- fields marked "packed" can be packed or not packed; it is up to the writing library to decide which to use
- "varint" encoding is itself ambiguous; additional unnecessary bytes are unexpected but not technically illegal - you could encode multiple blocks of 7-zero-bits after the actual value, for example

If you want to check *semantic* equality, you'll have to parse the data and post-process *that*.